# Im trying to calculate cartesian distance between two points using classes

Tags: python

```
import random
class point:
    def __init__(self,p):
        self.p = p
    def fill_point(self):
        x = random.uniform(0,100)
        y = random.uniform(0,100)
        z = random.uniform(0,100)
        self.p = [x,y,z]
        return self.p
    def distance_between_points(self,p1,p2):
        D = ((self.p1[0]-self.p2[0])**2 + (self.p1[1]-self.p2[1])**2 + (self.p1[2]-self.p2[2])**2)**(1/2)
        return D
def main():
    point1 = point(fill_point())
    point2 = point(fill_point())

    Distance = distance_between_points(point1,point2)
    print(Distance)

main()
```

im quite new to classes and am having a hard time understanding what im doing wrong.

Comment: First, get your indentation correct.

Comment: `distance_between_points` is a class method, not a stand-alone function which seems to be not what you want

Comment: please remember to accept the better answer

Comment: The indentation error is just a result of me copying the code incorrectly into stack exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import random
from math import sqrt

class Point:
    def __init__(self, name='anonym_point',x=0,y=0,z=0):
        self.name = name
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

    @property
    def coord(self):
        return (self.x, self.y, self.z)

    def __repr__(self):
        return ("{} has coordinate {}  {}  {}".format(self.name, self.x, self.y, self.z))
    

def makepoint(namepoint):
    return Point(namepoint, random.uniform(0,100), random.uniform(0,100), random.uniform(0,100))


def distance_between_points(p1,p2):
    dist = sqrt((p2.x-p1.x)**2 + (p2.y-p1.y)**2 + (p2.z-p1.z)**2)
    print("distance between point ",p1.name," and the point ",p2.name,"  : ",dist)


point1 = makepoint("p1")
point2 = makepoint("p2")

print(point1)
print(point2)

Distance = distance_between_points(point1,point2)
```

Comment: very interesting, can you explain the use of @property ?

Comment: it gives possibility to give dynamic result, ie self.squareX = self.X^2

Comment: https://zestedesavoir.com/tutoriels/954/notions-de-python-avancees/3-further/3-accessors-descriptors/#3-3-properties

Comment: thanks! i never used properties but they are a really powerful instrument...

Answer (score 0):

i think that what you are trying to do is something like this.

```
import math
class Point():
    def __init__(self,x,y,z):
        self.coordinates = (x,y,z)
    def distance(self,point):
        return math.sqrt((point.coordinates[0] - self.coordinates[0])**2 + (point.coordinates[1] - self.coordinates[1])**2 + (point.coordinates[1] - self.coordinates[1])**2)

a = Point(4,2,8)
b = Point(2,7,3)
print(a.distance(b))
```

what you are doing by executing this python code is simply creating a "Point" class, this point class has an attribute (coordinates) that contains its coordinates into a tuple.
so to create a point object you just have to use this code `point = Point(x_coordinates,y_coordinates,z_coordinates)`.
In the last line the code calculates the distance between two points, in that case you are calculating the distance of "b" respect to "a", but you could also do viceversa by doing something like this: `print(b.distance(a))`
to calculate the distance between random point all you have to do is this:

```
import math, random
class Point():
    def __init__(self,x,y,z):
        self.coordinates = (x,y,z)
    def distance(self,point):
        return math.sqrt((point.coordinates[0] - self.coordinates[0])**2 + (point.coordinates[1] - self.coordinates[1])**2 + (point.coordinates[1] - self.coordinates[1])**2)

r = lambda: random.uniform(0,100)

a = Point(r(),r(),r())
b = Point(r(),r(),r())
print(a.distance(b))
```

this is how to do that, but i really don't understand why you should calculate the distance between two random numbers

Comment: There is no useful outcome to this exercise, its just practice.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are accessing the class method just as a normal method, you need to initialize class object first then call the method by class object you created, again use only the variables you are sure you need,. keeping code easy for you because I think you already know what you needed I did this

```
import random
class Point:
    def fill_point(self):
        x = random.uniform(0,100)
        y = random.uniform(0,100)
        z = random.uniform(0,100)
        p = [x,y,z]
        return p
    def distance_between_points(self,p1,p2):
            D = ((p1[0]-p2[0])**2 + (p1[1]-p2[1])**2 + (p1[2]-p2[2])**2)**(1/2)
            return D
def main():
    obj = Point()
    point1 = obj.fill_point()
    point2 = obj.fill_point()

    distance = obj.distance_between_points(point1,point2)
    print(distance)

main()
```

it would not kill if you try to understand python classes better, python best naming, etc...

Comment: I was showing him how class methods work that is all coz if i made it a method then how would not have gained anything from the code

Comment: Thank you I was able to figure out the question. I am trying to learn classes currently so thats the goal. The best way to learn for me is by practicing examples.